# How can I write my callback function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When `regame()` is called I call another function inside it i.e. `anim1()` by passing reset function as a callback function. However reset gets executed along with `anim1()` itself. I want my custom animation to end and then call the `reset()`.

```js
function regame() {
  $(".title").text("GAME OVER");
  anim1(reset);
  pc = [];
  user = [];
}

function reset() {
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches)
    $(".title").text("Touch anywhere on the screen to start   the game");
  else
    $(".title").text("Press any key to start the game");
}

function anim1(callback) {
  var blre = ["black", "red"];
  var i = 0;
  var count = 0;
  var anime = setInterval(function() {
    $("body").css("background-color", blre[0 + i]);
    $(".title").css("color", blre[1 - i]);
    ++count;
    i = count % 2;
    if (count >= 7)
      clearInterval(anime);
  }, 150);
  callback();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Presumably you need to call `callback()` where the interval is cleared (I'm assuming this is where the animation ends). This is just an assumption though as your snippet is missing all relevant HTML and CSS, so we can't see anything actually working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `anim1` function to look like this:

```
function anim1(callback) {
  var blre = ["black", "red"];
  var i = 0;
  var count = 0;
  var anime = setInterval(function() {
    $("body").css("background-color", blre[0 + i]);
    $(".title").css("color", blre[1 - i]);
    ++count;
    i = count % 2;
    if (count >= 7)
      callback();
      clearInterval(anime);
  }, 150);      
}
```

That way, `callback()` doesn't get called until your `clearInterval` also gets called

Comment: Thank you @TKoL for this.This worked when both clearInterval and callback are called inside the if block.